# When does the NDA on iOS 7 expire?

Tags: iphone, ios

Not really a programming question but it is related, can't seem to find any info. My assumption is it expires when it's released on the 18th?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it expires on the 18th. Once the software has been publicly released, there is no longer reason for non-disclosure.